# SQL Server update date values so they are greater than or equal to other date values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing three date fields (StartDate, EndDate, PaymentDate)

The current data in the table is a mess where an EndDate can be before the StartDate and a PaymentDate can be before StartDate.

Is there a way to **convert** the dates so they meet the following constraints
StartDate cannot be equal or greater than EndDate
PaymentDate cannot be less than EndDate

The loss of current data is irrelevant, as long as the new values meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set them to null

```
UPDATE [table] SET EndDate=NULL WHERE StartDate>EndDate
UPDATE [table] SET PaymentDate=NULL WHERE EndDate>PaymentDate
```

to set them to minimum acceptable

```
UPDATE [table] SET EndDate=StartDate WHERE StartDate>EndDate
UPDATE [table] SET PaymentDate=EndDate WHERE EndDate>PaymentDate
```

Comment: The bottom option works best for me since the date fields cannot be null.
Thank you for the answer!